# What category should I specify for gross salary in Quicken?

Tags: salary, quicken

I'm using [Quicken 2013](https://qlc.intuit.com/questions/171719-what-category-should-i-specify-for-gross-salary) and I'm trying to split my "Gross Salary" (specified as Pay Rate on my pay stub) from my "Deductions" specified as (Current Deductions on my pay stub) using the line items on my pay stub.

From the menu I looked in Tools->Category List and found two categories...Salary and Net Salary.  As I understand it "Net Salary" is your take home pay, but I don't know what "Salary" is, but it doesn't seem like it's Gross Salary.

How can I set this up in a Quicken-Friendly manner?

Comment: Quicken allows you to set up your own categories if you like, and so why not create a new category called "Gross Salary" and give it all the attributes you like? Alternatively, you can **edit** Quicken's pre-defined categories and give them whatever attributes you like. Note that for many people, "Gross Salary" could well use subcategories named "Taxable Salary" and "NonTaxable Salary" where the latter would be where you put contributions to Traditional 401k plans. By the way, I vote to close as too localized.

Answer (score 2):

"Salary" is what you want. Quicken treats it as gross salary and has tied the tax category "W-2: Salary or wages" to it.

Did you know that Quicken has a paycheck wizard built in? You can use it to track all of the line items on your paycheck. Go to "**Tools -> Manage Bill and Income Reminders**", then at the top click "**Create New -> Income Reminder**".

At the new window, at the bottom, click "**Paycheck Setup Wizard**" to begin tracking your gross pay.

Apparently I don't have enough rep to post a picture directly, so here is a link to a picture of where to find the Paycheck Setup Wizard. [Paycheck Setup Wizard location](http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v504/jeli/Capture.png)